# Subir archivos PDF, DOCX etc... a un servidor desde app Android

Tags: android, webservice

Estoy intentando subir un archivo PDF o DOCX, o cual quier archivo desde mi aplicación Android a una carpeta en un servidor que de momento se encuentra local mi carpeta, el problema es que no he conseguido subir los archivos, he estado buscando tutoriales pero solamente encuentro como subir una imagen, no se si para subir algún documento o archivo adjunto debo seguir un proceso similar al de subir imágenes?

He intentando usar retrofit y httpok3 pero muchas veces me da un error mi aplicación al intentare ejecutar después de añadir estas librerías, el error es porque me aparecen clases duplicadas o estilos duplicados.

Este es el Archivo PHP que estoy usando para subir los documentos a una ruta local en mi equipo:

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$database="mgrex";
$username="root";
$password="";

//Ruta de las carpetas donde se guardaran los documentos PDF
$path = "uploadFiles/";
$actualPath = "http://192.168.1.64/appAndroid/$path";

//response array
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    //Revisamos si recibimos los parametros correctos
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['pdf']['name'])){

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

        //obtenemos el nombre del request
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        //Obtenemos la informacion del archivo
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['pdf']['name']);

        //Obtenemos la extencion del archivo
        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        //URl para guardar en la base de datos
        $file_url = $actualPath . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

        //file path para guardar en el servidor
        $file_path = $path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension;

        try{
            //Guardando el archivo
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],$file_path);

            $consulta = "INSERT INTO reportessim(usuario,titulo,mensaje,archivoAdjunto,idReporte) VALUES(prueba,prueba,prueba,'{$file_url}',134234)";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        }catch(Exception $e){

        }


    }
}

?>
```

Y este es el código que estoy intentando usar, el mismo que uso para subir varias imágenes al servidor, este código si funciona pero solo con imágenes, puedo hacer uso de este código para subir documentos PDF a mi carpeta del servidor?

```
public void uploadDocumentos(){
        final ProgressDialog cargando = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Enviando reporte...", "Espere por favor");
        //Vamos a validar lo de los documentos
        for (int i = 0; i < catalogoImagen.size(); i++ ){
            final int position = i;
            magicCount = 1 + magicCount;

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_FILE_PDF, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    cargando.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    cargando.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("ERRORUP","Error: "+error.getMessage());
                }
            }){
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                    String imagen = catalogoImagen.get(position);
                    Log.i("ENVIANDO","Imagen: "+catalogoImagen.get(position));
                    String nombre = catalogoNombres.get(position);
                    Log.i("NOMBRER","El nombre asignado es: "+nombre);
                    Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                    params.put(KEY_IMAGE, imagen);
                    params.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombre);
                    params.put(KEY_NOMBRE_USUARIO, nombre_global);
                    params.put(KEY_TITULO_REPORTE, tituloReporteG);
                    params.put(KEY_CUERPO_REPORTE, cuerpoReporteG);
                    params.put(KEY_ID_REPORTE, idReporte_global);

                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            //Validar la forma de limpiar la galeria
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Enrique, podrias subir el código que has ocupado y las respuestas que has obtenido para ver donde puede haber un error

Comment: @sioesi listo ya lo agregue, es el codigo que uso para subir imagenes, pero puedo usar este codigo para enviar tambien documentos al servidor?

Comment: los documentos e imagenes se tratan de forma distinta, que revuelve la funcion `catalogoImagen.get` ?

Comment: Ese es un arreglo donde estoy guardando las imagenes que selecciona el usuario, porque puedo enviar multiples imagenes a la vez pero realemente estoy intentando adaptar el codigo para enviar documentos al servidor

Comment: mira te dejo un link donde te ayudan facilmente a subir un documento a un servidor y también esta con PHP https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/upload-pdf-file-server-android/, espero te sirva

Comment: Si habia visto ese tutorial de echo, el problema es que cuando importo esta libreria "compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'" y despues intento ejecutar mi aplicacion me da un error de que se duplican archivos o estilos

Comment: Enrique pudiste solucionarlo con el enlace de sioesi?, me ayudaria bastante que me dijeras como, ya que lo implemente pero obtengo un error, eh visto que es por la version, ya que me da la ruta absoluta del pdf.